# Access JMSQueue via JMX on clustered environment

Tags: jms, cluster-computing, weblogic-10.x, mbeans

**Configuration:** WLS-cluster (10.3) with two nodes #1 and #2. One migratable JMSServer currently available on #1. One migratable JMSQueue.

**Problem:**
Some EJB is populating the JSMQueue with a message with timeToDeliever set to 60 sec.  (not visible in 60 sec.) and another EJB is going to use JMX to get that (not visible) message before it gets visible. If this other EJB executes on #2, it can't find the JMSServer and therefore not pop the message. The code works fine on a non clustered environment:

```
    public class PurgeWLSQueue {

        private static final String WLS_USERNAME = "weblogic";
        private static final String WLS_PASSWORD = "weblogic";
        private static final String WLS_HOST = "localhost";
        private static final int WLS_PORT = 7001;
        private static final String JMS_SERVER = "wlsbJMSServer";
        private static final String JMS_DESTINATION = "test.q";

        private static JMXConnector getMBeanServerConnector(String jndiName) throws Exception {
            Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
            JMXServiceURL serviceURL = new JMXServiceURL("t3", WLS_HOST, WLS_PORT, jndiName);
            h.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, WLS_USERNAME);
            h.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, WLS_PASSWORD);
            h.put(JMXConnectorFactory.PROTOCOL_PROVIDER_PACKAGES, "weblogic.management.remote");
            JMXConnector connector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceURL, h);
            return connector;
        }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                JMXConnector connector = 
                  getMBeanServerConnector("/jndi/"+RuntimeServiceMBean.MBEANSERVER_JNDI_NAME);
                MBeanServerConnection mbeanServerConnection = 
                  connector.getMBeanServerConnection();

                ObjectName service = new ObjectName("com.bea:Name=RuntimeService,Type=weblogic.management.mbeanservers.runtime.RuntimeServiceMBean");
                ObjectName serverRuntime = (ObjectName) mbeanServerConnection.getAttribute(service, "ServerRuntime");
                ObjectName jmsRuntime = (ObjectName) mbeanServerConnection.getAttribute(serverRuntime, "JMSRuntime");
                ObjectName[] jmsServers = (ObjectName[]) mbeanServerConnection.getAttribute(jmsRuntime, "JMSServers");
                for (ObjectName jmsServer: jmsServers) {
                    if (JMS_SERVER.equals(jmsServer.getKeyProperty("Name"))) {
                        ObjectName[] destinations = (ObjectName[]) mbeanServerConnection.getAttribute(jmsServer, "Destinations");
                        for (ObjectName destination: destinations) {
                            if (destination.getKeyProperty("Name").endsWith("!"+JMS_DESTINATION)) {
                                Object o = mbeanServerConnection.invoke(
                                    destination,
                                    "deleteMessages",
                                    new Object[] {""},        // selector expression
                                    new String[] {"java.lang.String"});
                                System.out.println("Result: "+o);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                connector.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

(This code is borrowed from Miklos Csuka on this forum)

Are there any other ways on getting that messages without specifying JMSServer, i.e can I directly address the JMSQueue? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, solved it!
For others facing the same problem, use the domain runtime service instead:

```
ObjectName service = new ObjectName("com.bea:Name=DomainRuntimeService,Type=weblogic.management.mbeanservers.domainruntime.DomainRuntimeServiceMBean");
```

and be sure to access the *admin* port on the WLS-cluster.